# Uso de array en variable de sesion

Tags: php, array, session

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Me gustaría guardar en una variable de sesión el valor de dos campos que paso mediante $_post desde un formulario y que esta variable de sesión vaya almacenando los datos de dichos campos hasta que la destruya con la intención de poder rellenar una tabla con los datos almancenados en la misma.

¿Alguién me puede indicar cómo debo almacenar los datos del formulario en una array de sesión?.

Estoy utilizando Php. Mi código es el siguiente pero me lanzo un error de:

> Array String conversión.

```
$art = $_POST["select-productos"];
$und = $_POST["und-productos"];

$productos = array("articulo" => $art, "cantidad" => $und);

if (empty($_SESSION["listadecompra"])) {
    $i = 0;
    $_SESSION["listadecompra"][$i] = $productos;
} else {
    $i = count($_SESSION["listadecompra"]);
    $i++;
    $_SESSION["listadecompra"][$i] = $productos;
}

/* Creamos tabla de contenido */
$listado = $_SESSION["listadecompra"];

foreach ($listado as $value) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
}

//var_dump($_SESSION["listadecompra"]);
echo "Total de productos: " . $i . "<br>";
```

Lo que pretendo es poder ir incrementando el array que almaceno en la sesión con los datos que voy recibiendo del formulario para luego mostrarlos en una tabla.

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado o intentado? ¿Estás usando PHP? Conviene que pongas la etiqueta específica del lenguaje que usas y el código que estás intentando.

Comment: Prueba el `foreach` así: **`foreach ($listado as $value) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $value["articulo"] . "</td><td>" . $value["cantidad"] . "</td></tr>";
}`** Si sigue sin funcionar descomenta esta línea: `var_dump($_SESSION["listadecompra"]);` y dinos qué resultado arroja para ver cómo está constituido el array realmente.

Comment: Hola Cedano.<br>Me lanza un error en esta línea $_SESSION["listadecompra"][$i] = $productos; indicándome Array to string conversion. ¿Qué puede ser?. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Probaste el código como te dije en mi anterior comentario? A mi me funciona bien poniendo los índices del array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El  *`Array String conversión`* ocurriría en esta línea:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>";
```

porque no estás haciendo referencia a los índices que tendría el array.

Haciendo esto debería resolverse el problema:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $value["articulo"] . "</td><td>" . $value["cantidad"] . "</td></tr>";
```

Otro error que estás cometiendo, esta vez de lógica, es que te estás enroyando demasiado al pensar *que debes indicar al código en qué posición del array debe insertarse el nuevo dato*. Por eso te empeñas en una verificación de si está vacío, en un contador `$i` y demás historias. Con esta notación: `$array[]=$elemento`, se inserta un elemento en la primera o en la última posición del array según éste se encuentre o no vacío, no veo por qué tengas que preguntar primero si está vacío o preguntar por su total de elementos para luego aumentar en uno e insertar ahí. Todo eso se hace sólo usando la notación ya mencionada. Además con tu lógica, en el primer caso, cuando imprimes esto:

```
echo "Total de productos: " . $i . "<br>";
```

Te imprimirá `0`, cuando hay ya un elemento.

Voy a simplificar considerablemente tu lógica en el código de respuesta:

```
$art = $_POST["select-productos"];
$und = $_POST["und-productos"];
$listado = $_SESSION["listadecompra"];

$productos = array("articulo" => $art, "cantidad" => $und);
$listado[] = $productos;

/* Creamos tabla de contenido */

foreach ($listado as $value) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $value["articulo"] . "</td><td>" . $value["cantidad"] . "</td></tr>";
}


$allProducts = count( $listado);
echo "Total de productos: $allProducts<br>";
```

Comment: Hola Cedano. Hay algo que no comprendo, guardas en la variable $listado la session y luego crear un array con el mismo nombre, ¿porque?.

Comment: @jmrufo ¿Te refieres a esto: `$listado = $_SESSION["listadecompra"];` y luego a esto: `$listado[] = $productos;` cierto? No guardo la sesión, guardo la clave de la sesión que interesa aquí, o sea `listadecompra` y en `$listado[] = $productos;` no creo un array, sino que a ese array le agrego otro elemento, el cual se agregará en la última posición. Precisamente con eso evitas liarte con el `empty` y la variable `$i`, como te comento en la respuesta. He probado el código y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Lo que hago ahí es poner en práctica esta afirmación de la respuesta: ***Con esta notación: `$array[]=$elemento`
, se inserta un elemento en la primera o en la última posición del array según éste se encuentre o no vacío...***

Comment: Pues me lanza el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\DWS_carrito\carrito.php:55 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown, y se genera al intentar almacenar $productos dentro del array (listado[] = $productos). Utilizo la versión 7.1 de Php ¿Puede ser eso?

Comment: @jmrufo ¿podrías por favor mostrar un `var_dump` de tu variable de sesión? He emulado el código y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: $listado = $_SESSION["listadecompra"];var_dump($_SESSION["listadecompra"]);$productos = array("articulo" => $art, "cantidad" => $und);$listado[] = $productos;.Esto muestra String(0)""

Comment: @jmrufo qué es lo que muestra `String(0)`? Necesito ver el resultado de esto: `var_dump($_SESSION);` para ver qué es lo que hay en tu variable de sesión. Estás usando `session_start();` ante todo (supongo).

Comment: Al inicio de la página indico <?php
    session_start();
    
    if (!isset($_SESSION["listadecompra"])) {
        $_SESSION["listadecompra"] = "";
    }
?>

Sin embargo el vardump no llega a mostrarse ya que el error detiene el proceso de ejecución.

Comment: Buenos días Cedano. He comprobado que si modifico el nombre de la variable $listado a la que en primera instancia se asigna la variable de sesión el error desaparece pero sin embargo no acumula los datos. Es decir, solo guarda el último dato procesado.

Comment: @jmrufo a mí me funciona bien, ¿puedes mostrar cómo lo estás haciendo, quizá editando tu pregunta y poniendo el código actual al final de la misma?

Comment: Hola Cedano. Ya he dado con el error, tenía un if que estaba haciendo de las suyas. Un único comentario. Antes de $allProducts = count ($listado) he añadio $_Session["listadodecompra"] = $listado; para que me vaya acumulando todos los registros enviados desde el formulario.

Muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegro @jmrufo, aunque lo último que comentas ya se hizo arriba, en la tercer línea del código. Si a partir de ahí trabajas sólo con `$listado` no hace falta nada más.